# Expression.Assign Right Property Must be readable

Tags: c#, xml, lambda, expression-trees

Getting the following Arguement Exception ("Expression must be readableParameter name: right") running this code and cant figure out why.

This code is meant to create a delegate to take the Attributes in a XmlNode and map them to properties on an object.

```
private static Action<XmlNode, T>   createMapperFunction() {
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToArray();
            var xmlNodeParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(XmlNode), "x");
            var resultParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "result");
         //   Expression.
            var exprList = new List<Expression>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < props.Length ; i++) {
                if (props[i].PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    exprList.Add(Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(resultParameter,props[i].Name), 
                            Expression.Property(
                                Expression.Property(
                                    Expression.Property(xmlNodeParameter,"Attributes"), "ItemOf", Expression.Constant(props[i].Name)),"InnerText")));
            }
            var body = Expression.Block(exprList);
            return Expression.Lambda<Action<XmlNode, T>>(body, xmlNodeParameter, resultParameter).Compile();



        }
```

Comment: Could you help us help you by providing *which line* causes this exception?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt splitting your big expression into multiple expressions. Makes the code much easier to read and debug.

Comment: its the Expression.Assign that throws the exception.

Ill edit the post as soon as I get a chance and split it to multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XmlAttribute.InnerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.innertext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is write-only.  Using `XmlAttribute.InnerText` as the right-side of an assignment won't work because the `Assign` expression can't read the value to assign it to the left-side.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You have no clue, so you downvote the answer?  `XmlAttribute.InnerText` is **write-only**, you can't perform an operation like `newValue = xmlAttribute.InnerText` because it doesn't have a getter.

Comment: Interesting you are right it is write only which is interesting cause I have working code that reads this property.

   string tableName = n.Attributes["TableName"].InnerText;

Comment: Together with the read-only vs. write-typo it made the answer quite nonsensical. I've fixed the write-only one for you. Two such mistakes at once is more than my error correction can manage :P So I think the downvote was justified.